# parameters intruduction in function give error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the text of some paragraph when I click different buttons but I want to avoid to write every time the whole function changing only two text elements.

This is the code with no parameters:

```
$('.ilBorgo').click(good);
function good() {
    if ($('#page').hasClass('content') === false) {
        $('#page').addClass('content');
        $('.title').text("text1");
        $('.text').text("text2");
        $('#slider').removeAttr("id");
        $('.container').css("background-image", 'url' + imgPath[0]);
    } else {
        $('#page').removeClass('content');
        $('.container').attr("id", "slider");
        $('.title').text("");
        $('.text').text("");
    };
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "it's running!";
};
```

My problem is that when I try to add parameters to make my code looks better, I get it, but the event triggered without click the button, suddenly after the page loads.

When I click on it nothing happens, while it should toggle and make disappear the text's div.

This is the code with parameters:

```
$('.ilBorgo').click(good("hello", "world"));

function good(a, b) {
    if ($('#page').hasClass('content') === false) {
        $('#page').addClass('content');
        $('.title').text(a);
        $('.text').text(b);
        $('#slider').removeAttr("id");
        $('.container').css("background-image", 'url' + imgPath[0]);
    } else {
        $('#page').removeClass('content');
        $('.container').attr("id", "slider");
        $('.title').text("");
        $('.text').text("");
    };
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "it's running!";
};
```

Comment: Why are you removing the id from the slider?

Answer (score 2):

You're confused about when the function is executed.

Your original code:

```
$('.ilBorgo').click(good); // function is executed on click
```

Doesn't call good. It only passes the function *by value* to `.click`

However, your new code *does call `good`*:

```
$('.ilBorgo').click(good("hello", "world")); // function is executed HERE
                                             // and return value is passed to click.
```

The equivalent form *without parameters* would be:

```
$('.ilBorgo').click(good()); // bug easier to see
```

See the problem?

What you want is to delay the execution until the actual click.

A simple way to do that is to use an anonymous function around the call:

```
$('.ilBorgo').click(function () { // .click receives a function
    good("hello", "world");       // good() is only called once we clicked
});
```

The other solution is to have `hello` return a function:

```
function good(a, b){
    // don't execute anything here!
    // just make a function that uses a and b!
    return function () {
        if($('#page').hasClass('content')===false){
            $('#page').addClass('content');
            $('.title').text(a);
            $('.text').text(b);
            $('#slider').removeAttr("id");
            $('.container').css("background-image", 'url'+imgPath[0]);
        }else{
            $('#page').removeClass('content');
            $('.container').attr("id","slider");
            $('.title').text("");
            $('.text').text("");
        };
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "it's running!";
    };
};
```

Comment: This is the typical way to construct an event handler (a function that handles the click event, or runs when you click the button).

Comment: @BobRodes not sure what you mean?

Comment: Yeah it works , but i want to reuse the function for other  button, with other parameters, my goal it's to have a clean and working code..

Comment: Okay. Then another solution is to instead *return a function* from `hello` :).

Comment: @atul answered the problem very well, but when i try to change the string hello with another text string stored in a variable called text1 it return the hello string but not the text1 one, which contains much more text, so i cannot put it in the function parameters...

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
 $('.ilBorgo').click(good("hello", "world"));
```

then the browser will call the good method as soon as it interpret it that's why it is getting called on page refresh/load. Instead try this:

```
$(".ilBorgo").click(good.bind(this, "Hello", "World"));
```

in this case good method will get call on the button click. you can check how [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) works

Comment: Thank you, your code works great!!could you please tell me how it works,in easy words??

Comment: **function abc(){.....}** // this will register in the browser memory as function declaration. However when the browser see **abc()** it will interpret as function call,  and therefore calls the function abc immediately.
Same is the case with  `$('.ilBorgo').click(good("hello", "world"));`
here also browser interpret good as function call, hence get  call on page load.
Instead, `good.bind(this, "Hello", "World")` won't get call immediately, It tells the browser execute the good method in the **this** context, whenever it is invoked on button click.
sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: thank you, i'm not english too, however if you don't mind, could you please tell me why when i try to change the string "world" with another text string stored in a variable called text1 it return the hello string but not the text1 one, which contains much more text. i don't know if the problem is because i stored the text between [ ], or if i should store it in other way.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it.If possible, can you post the js fiddle link showing they way you are trying, that will be easy to debug.

Comment: i think you forget to declare the variable text1, i am not seeing any declaration for it, you are just using it.

Comment: no, i declared it just before  the end of the main, and if i use it out of the parameters it works.

Comment: ok got it. you are storing it in an array, therefore you have to do this 
`good.bind(this, "Hello", text1.join(" ")) // if the whole content of the array you want to print`
otherwise,
`good.bind(this, "Hello", text1[i])  // where i represents any specific array index`

Comment: i tried both the way but it don't trigger the event :(, now i go eat maybe later i will got it.

Comment: thank you for your time, in the end i make it a very,very long string and put it at the top of the program, i think that it could not read it, thank you again :)

Comment: that is happening because of variable hoisting in javascript.
you can check the following references for better understanding

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/

Comment: does this solve your issue?? if yes then accept the answer :P :D

Comment: I tried many time to do it, but unfortunatly i haven't enough reputation to do it, when i would have more than 15 i will sure  vote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use your click event as

```
$(".ilBorgo").click({param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}, good);

function good(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
}
```

This is the way you pass parameters to the function on click event.